# Enable background color of paragraphs <p> when there is a bootstrap button with CSS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

The following fiddle allows paragraphs to be created dynamically as well as changing the background color and style of each paragraph `<p>`.

---

Is it possible, within the following fiddle, to still allow the background colors behind each dynamically created paragraph `<p>` to be printed and not removed.

The issue is, when attempting to print, the background color for each paragraph section is being removed  bootstrap CSS.

Attached is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WkWpE/34/)

An updated Fiddle would be very much appreciated as I am still new to coding.

Thank You!

HTML:

```
<div>
<div id="styles">
    <label>Color:
        <select data-property="color">
            <option disabled>Select color:</option>
            <option>red</option>
            <option>green</option>
            <option>blue</option>
        </select>
    </label>
    <label>Font-size:
        <select data-property="font-size">
            <option disabled>Select font-size:</option>
            <option>smaller</option>
            <option>10px</option>
            <option>12px</option>
            <option>14px</option>
            <option>16px</option>
            <option>18px</option>
            <option>20px</option>
            <option>larger</option>
        </select>
    </label>
    <label>Background-color:
        <select data-property="background-color">
            <option disabled>Select background-color:</option>
            <option>aqua</option>
            <option>fuchsia</option>
            <option>limegreen</option>
            <option>silver</option>
        </select>
    </label>
</div>
<div id="text_land">xzxz</div>
<textarea></textarea>
<button>Go</button>
```

JQuery:

```
$(function () {
$('button').on('click', function () {
    var v = $('#text_land + textarea').val(),
        paragraphs = '<p>' + v.split(/\n\n/).join('</p><p>') + '</p>';
    $(paragraphs).appendTo('#text_land');
});

$('select').on('change', function () {
    var targets = $('#text_land p'),
        property = this.dataset.property;

    targets.css(property, this.value);
}).prop('selectedIndex', 0);
});
```

Comment: Please explain your problem more clearly, point by point. By reading your above post, i totally got lost.

Comment: The issue is that the background colors behind each dynamically created paragraph are not displaying when trying to print due to the bootstrap button.

Comment: What is the default color you are trying to use with your <p> tag.

Comment: The background color is dynamic from a dropdown list for the user to custom choose the background color.

Comment: I don't see you applying the dynamic CSS to your <p> tag before adding a new <p> tag. As a result CSS are not getting applied.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure got your question... You could try to apply values from your selects to the just created paragraph.

```
$('select').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    paragraphs.css($this.data('property'), $this.val());
});
```

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/xt61b7ba/)

Comment: However, when printing, the background color the user selects does not remain.

Comment: When I click "Go" button the new paragraph appears with styles set by selects. Isn't it what you try to get?

Comment: Please see the updated fiddle including a print button. Please note, when creating a paragraph dynamically, the user has the option to change the background colour. However I have added a print button to show how the background colour of each dynamic paragraph is being removed. http://jsfiddle.net/WkWpE/35

Comment: Ah, ok, now I got it. That's not because of dynamically added paragraphs but because of inline styles. They are ignored for print media. Use classnames to set background color.